# Sed: How to replace a string found after a specific pattern is located in a file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

If I have the following list in a file:

```
integer, parameter :: ni = 1024
integer, parameter :: nj = 256
integer, parameter :: nk = 16
```

and want to search based on the string 'ni =', and then replace the string that follows (in this case '1024') with a new string like '512' for example (I would like to preserve the space). How can I use sed for this? Note that I would like to just essentially wipe anything that comes after the equal sign, this is because sometimes the string will not be a simple integer, it might be something like '1.D0'. And in some cases there may be comments ahead. So I just want to wipe out whatever is in front of the equal sign and replace with the new value.

The result would be:

```
integer, parameter :: ni = 512
integer, parameter :: nj = 256
integer, parameter :: nk = 16
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GNU sed supports extended regular expressions if you give it the `-r` flag.

```
sed -re 's/(:: ni =)[^=]*$/\1 512/' file
```

Better yet, match for multiple whitespace.

```
sed -re 's/(::\s+ni\s+=)[^=]*$/\1 512/' file
```

The `\1` is a  reference to what's matched in parentheses `( )`, so we replace with `\1` and a new value.

Comment: What if its `ni:1024`? without a space

Answer (score 6):

If I understand you correctly, something like this should do it:

`sed 's/\(ni = \).*/\1REPLACEMENT/'`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/:: ni = [0-9][0-9]*$/:: ni = 512/'
```

This looks for plausible context around the match specified to minimize the chance of finding `ni` somewhere in another string.

Comment: it's better to write `sed -e 's/:: ni = [0-9]+$/:: ni = 512/'`

Comment: @AntonAstafiev: that depends on how widely you want the code to work.  Some variants of `sed` support `+` without further switches; many do not and POSIX doesn't require them to do so. You could use `[0-9]\{1,\}` to do it, but what I wrote is more easily understood.