# How do i search & replace using sed and not include a group of characters?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

Hello in the following sed command i need to have in the second group of parenthesis code that will NOT accept the following group of words: Inc The Ltd LLC

It will break the following data in list.txt to have each company name on a line, the company names are after commas but some times "Inc", "Ltd", "LLC", and "The" follow a company.

This is pretty advance regular expression that i cant seem to get.

```
sed -re 's/([a-zA-Z.]), (Need code here)/\1\n\2/g' list.txt
```

list.txt has the following data:

```
Electronic Arts, Inc., Electronic Arts Ltd.
Activision Publishing, Inc., ak tronic Software & Services GmbH
Coplin Software
Electronic Arts, Inc.
Electronic Arts, Inc.
In-Fusio
Activision Publishing, Inc.
Domark Ltd.
Electronic Arts, Inc.
Electronic Arts, Inc.
Aspyr Media, Inc., Electronic Arts, Inc.
Activision Deutschland GmbH, Activision Publishing, Inc., ak tronic Software & Services GmbH, Noviy Disk, Square Enix Co., Ltd.
Electronic Arts, Inc.
Electronic Arts, Inc., Electronic Arts Ltd.
Electronic Arts, Inc.
Electronic Arts, Inc.
Electronic Arts, Inc., Electronic Arts Square, K.K., MGM Interactive
Electronic Arts Ltd.
```

expected output(notice the commas):

```
GarageGames, Inc.
The Avalon Hill Game Company
Microforum International, The
Telenet Japan Co., Ltd.
Glu Mobile, Inc.
Warner Bros. Digital Distribution
Atari, Inc.
```

Comment: You want to not match a group of characters, or specific words?

Comment: You use `[^abcxyz]` to match a character that isn't in `xyzabc`.

Comment: Can you post and short example of `list.txt` ?

Comment: its specific words, i already corrected the question.

Comment: short example of list.txt
`Activision Deutschland GmbH, Activision Publishing, Inc., ak tronic Software & Services`
it should break the company names on the comma but you see that some do not need breaking when there is a comma because part of the company name still continues.

Comment: The job of decoding some text fields and outputting them in a different form is much easier to do with `awk`, you should check it out. Regexp are not the solution to all world's problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's/([^,]), (?!Inc|LLC|The|Ltd)/\1\n/g' list.txt
```

Comment: sed did NOT support the section `(?!Inc|LLC|The|Ltd)` so @hwnd used perl which now i think is better than SED and more useful. But your answer still needs a little tweak. i ended up using `perl -pe 's/([a-zA-Z\.]), (?!Inc|LLC|The|Ltd)/\1\n\2/g' list.txt` it still doesnt behave the way i intent but its close. If a company name is `ABC company, IncaCola, Inc.` it will not split this into two since `IncaCola, Inc.` starts with `Inc` . Its close those, thanks @hwnd

Comment: That's when you can adjust for word boundaries `\b`

Answer (score 3):

Based on your example `list.txt`, you can try this:

```
  sed -re 's/(, )?(Inc.|The|Ltd.?|LLC)//g' list.txt| tr ',' '\n' | sed -re 's/(.*)/\1/g' | sed -re '/^\s*$/d' | sed -re 's/(^ | $)//g'
```

***OUTPUTS:***

```
Electronic Arts
Electronic Arts
Activision Publishing
ak tronic Software & Services GmbH
Coplin Software
Electronic Arts
Electronic Arts
In-Fusio
Activision Publishing
Domark
Electronic Arts
Electronic Arts
Aspyr Media
Electronic Arts
Activision Deutschland GmbH
Activision Publishing
ak tronic Software & Services GmbH
Noviy Disk
Square Enix Co.
Electronic Arts
Electronic Arts
Electronic Arts
Electronic Arts
Electronic Arts
Electronic Arts
Electronic Arts Square
K.K.
MGM Interactive
```

***NOTE:***

You can pipe the above list to `awk` and display only unique results, ex:

```
sed -re 's/(, )?(Inc.|The|Ltd.?|LLC)//g' list.txt| tr ',' '\n' | sed -re 's/(.*)/\1/g' | sed -re '/^\s*$/d' | sed -re 's/(^ | $)//g'| awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

Outputs:

```
Electronic Arts
Activision Publishing
ak tronic Software & Services GmbH
Coplin Software
In-Fusio
Domark
Aspyr Media
Activision Deutschland GmbH
Noviy Disk
Square Enix Co.
Electronic Arts Square
K.K.
MGM Interactive
```

Comment: actually it needs to add a line break after each company name. Ideally it would have to be after each comma, but in my case the following are sometimes at the end "Inc." "The" "Ltd" "LLC" that need to be with the company name. i just included some of the contents of list.txt on my question.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: hwnd check the question, i posted the output.

Comment: @Tuga you can use the `-r` flag instead of escaping. `sed -re 's/(,\s*)?(Inc\.|The|Ltd|LLC)//g' file`

Comment: @hwnd I didn't know that! tks ;)

Comment: @Tuga see this [`man page`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed). The `-r` flag is for extended regular expressions =)

Comment: @hwnd I will! once again, tks for taking time to teach me something, after all, that's why we're here!

Comment: Of course, here's an example from one that I answered. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737398/sed-how-to-replace-a-string-found-after-a-specific-pattern-is-located-in-a-file/19737485#19737485)

Comment: ok, so i figured out how to do this in notepad++ but doesn't translate well in sed i search for `([a-zA-Z.]), (?!Inc|LLC|The|Ltd)` and replace with `\1\n\2` you're close @hwnd

Comment: `perl -pe 's/([a-zA-Z.]), (?!Inc|LLC|The|Ltd)/\1\n/g' list.txt`

Comment: @tuga With nearly 6000 in reputation, you should now that `cat` is not needed with programs like  `sed`

Comment: @jotne I actually know but didn't pay attention while testing the several pipes. Tks for pointing that.

Comment: @hwnd that works! you sir are a regex genius, post this as your answer and i'll give you credit, like you mention this doesn't work in SED but it does in perl: `perl -pe 's/([a-zA-Z\.]), (?!Inc|LLC|The|Ltd)/\1\n\2/g' list.txt`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -nr '/^ *([^,]+(, *(Inc\.?|The|Ltd\.?|LLC))?)(,(.*))?/ {
                   s//\1\n\5/
                   P
                   D
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

A `perl` version:

```
$ perl -anlF'(?!,[\x20](?:Inc|Ltd|LLC|The).?),[\x20]' -e '$n{$_}++ for @F; END { print join "\n", sort keys %n; }' test.txt
Activision Deutschland GmbH
Activision Publishing, Inc.
Aspyr Media, Inc.
Coplin Software
Domark Ltd.
Electronic Arts Ltd.
Electronic Arts Square
Electronic Arts, Inc.
In-Fusio
K.K.
MGM Interactive
Noviy Disk
Square Enix Co., Ltd.
ak tronic Software & Services GmbH
```